# change page title based on aria-current ="page" content

Tags: javascript, html, content-management-system

i have a problem with a dynamic website I need to to fix. This website has a custom built CMS, but this CMS does not change the page title just to add content and title for this content. The title of content does not has an ID attribute in the website page, but it has an aria-current="page" attribute common. So i was thinking if it is possible to make the content of this aria-current="page" attribute as page title. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWKR2.png)

i tried to look for an ID but could not find any.